# "Unable to create keystore" message from Unity for Android

Tags: unity, c#, android

I want to build a project with a release aab version.

Unity asks me to create a keystore, and when I create one, it show this message:

> Android/2023.1.911/Editor/2023.3.0a6/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools \ sdktools.jar " CommandinvokationFailure : Unable to create keystore . Please make sure the location of the keystore is valid . CommandinvokationFailure : Unable to create keystore . Please make sure the location of the keystore is valid .
>
> Android 2023.1.9f1 | Editor 2023.3.0a61Editor Data PlaybackEngines Android Player \ OpenJDK bin java.exe -Xmx4096M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir = " E : Android2023.1.9f11Editor 2023.3.0861Editor Data \ PlaybackEngines Android Player SDK cmdline - tools 16.0 " -Dfile.encoding - UTFB - jar

When I choose a different location, it also shows this message and refuses to create a keystore

Comment: Can you **edit your question** to show us the exact steps you're taking to create this keystore, and what location you're trying to create it in?

Comment: [Searching for the text of the error message](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22Unable+to+create+keystore%22&ia=web), I find this [Unity support thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/can-not-create-keystore.1481004/) which claims the problem has been fixed in versions 2023.1.11f1, 2023.2.0b7 and 2023.3.0a4 - have you tried updating to one of these versions?

Comment: I use 2023.3.0a6 version

Comment: I notice "2023.1.911" / "2023.1.9f" in the error messages - is it possible your Android support tools are from an older version? Uninstalling and reinstalling may help with this.